# String search in python - two lists

Tags: python, arrays, full-text-search

Say I have a string array  A =  ['abcbdefcd'] and  another string array 
T= ['ab', 'abc', 'def', 'cd', 'abcd']

I want to write a function that can search the array A and if it finds a string in T that is in A, return true or false.

I thought I would try

> for text in A:     if text in T:       print (true)
>
> else:
>
> print(false)

But this does not give me what I am looking for, can anyone suggest something else?

Comment: when you say `if it finds a string in T that is in A`, do mean that string is present in the list A or do mean the string is present as a substring in any element of A?

Comment: I want a method to search A for each small string in T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific request:

```
a = ['abcbdefcd'] 
t = ['ab', 'abc', 'def', 'cd', 'abcd']

for text in t:
    print(text in a[0])
```

output:

```
True
True
True
True
False
```

some notes:

1. name your variable in lowercase letters
2. you can use t = 'abcbdefcd' instead of t = ['abcbdefcd'], and code will be `if text in t` instead of `if text in t[0]`

Comment: Thank you - that's what I was  trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

this should achieve what youre looking for,

```
A =  ['abcbdefcd']

T =  ['ab', 'abc', 'def', 'cd', 'abcd']

result = False
for text in A:
    for sub_text in T:
        if (sub_text in text):
            result = True
            break

if (result):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you basically want to find the intersection of 2 lists. If List T contains elements that are also present in list A then Return true else return false.

To do this you have a variety of pythonic solutions:

**Method 1**:

```
bool(set(a) & set(b))
```

ie. Try something like this.

```
a = ['abc','bca','av']
b = ['ab','bc']
print(bool(set(a) & set(b))) # this would return true in this case
```

**Another method** to do it is by using a generator expression performing iteration on the lists:

```
a = set(a); any(i in a for i in b)
```

And **lastly** you can use the disjoint method of the frozen sets:

```
not set(a).isdisjoint(b)
```